# Sphider with Product Images in results page - Sphider 1.3.5

Tags: php

I hope this can be of great help to others, it took me awhile of PHP learning, but gave me a good PHP high when I pieced it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who are looking to put images next to your sphider results...
I use Sphider for indexing a product folder with thousands of items, here is an example of my file structure for use with this snippet:

www/

> product/
>
> > item1.php
> >
> > item2.php
> >
> > item3.php
>
> images/
>
> > item1.png
> >
> > item2.png
> >
> > item3.png

Insert this into sphider/templates/standard/search_results.html (or sphider/templates/dark/search_results.html) in line 75 just after " class="title">

```
<?PHP
        // Edit here
          $url_path = "http:// www.yoursite.com/product/";    // The url leading to your indexed pages.
          $url_ext = ".php";                                     // The file extension of indexed pages.
          $image_path = "../images/";                              // Path to image folder.
          $image_ext = ".png";                                       // The file extension of images.
        // To here

        $image = str_replace("$url_path", "$image_path", $url);
        $image = str_replace("$url_ext", "$image_ext", $image);
        if (file_exists($image)) { 
     // do nothing or Your Option
    } else { $image = $image_path . "ICS" . $image_ext; } ?>
        <img src="<?PHP print $image ?>" alt="" align="left" style="margin-right:10px; border:0;" />
```

Basically, if you have a page called 1234.php in your Sphider index, this will try to find picture 1234.png to go along side it of the search result. If an image is not found it will display a default image 'ICS.png' (Image Coming Soon).

Happy coding